# What could be some possible problems with this use of OpenMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I was trying to figure out how to parallelize a segment of code in OpenMP, where the inside of the for loop is independent from the rest of it.

Basically the project is dealing with particle systems, but I don't think that should relevant to the parallelization of the code. Is it a caching problem where the for loop divides the threads in a way such that the particles are not cached in each core in an efficient manner?

**Edit:** As mentioned by an answer below, I'm wondering why I'm not getting speedup.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned i = 0; i < psize-n_dead; ++i)
{
    s->particles[i].pos = s->particles[i].pos + dt * s->particles[i].vel;
    s->particles[i].vel = (1 - dt*.1) * s->particles[i].vel + dt*s->force;
    //  printf("%d", omp_get_thread_num());

}
```

Comment: It grows with time, but it is on the order of 1000s. So say 4000 in the simplest state, and probably going to 200000 at max.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether it's ***parallelized*** correctly, it looks fine. I don't see any data-races or loop-dependencies that could break it.

But I think you're wondering on why you aren't getting any speedup with parallelism.

Since you mentioned that the trip count, `psize-n_dead` will be on the order of `4000`. I'd say that's actually pretty small given the amount of work in the loop.

In other words, you don't have much total work to be worth parallelizing. So threading overhead is probably eating up any speedup that you should be gaining. If possible, you should try parallelizing at a higher level.

---

EDIT: You updated your comment to include up to 200000.

For larger values, it's likely that you'll be memory bound in some way. Your loop merely iterates through all the data doing very little work. So using more threads probably won't help much (if at all).

Answer (score 2):

There is no correctness issues such as data races in this piece of code.

Assuming that the number of particles to process is big enough to warrant parallelism, I do not see OpenMP related performance issues in this code. By default, OpenMP will split the loop iterations statically in equal portions across all threads, so any cache conflicts may only occur at the boundaries of these portions, i.e. just in a few iterations of the loop.

Unrelated to OpenMP (and so to the parallel speedup problem), possibly performance improvement can be achieved by switching from array-of-structs to struct-of-arrays, as this might help compiler to vectorize the code (i.e. use SIMD instructions of a target processor):

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned i = 0; i < psize-n_dead; ++i)
{
    s->particles.pos[i] = s->particles.pos[i] + dt * s->particles.vel[i];
    s->particles.vel[i] = (1 - dt*.1) * s->particles.vel[i] + dt*s->force;
}
```

Such reorganization assumes that most time all particles are processed in a loop like this one. Working with an individual particle requires more cache lines to be loaded, but if you process them all in a loop, the net amount of cache lines loaded is nearly the same.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Struct-of-Arrays. That never crossed my mind since I was just focused on the parallelism part.

Answer (score 1):

How sure are you that you're not getting speedup?

Trying it both ways - array of structs and struct of arrays, compiled with gcc -O3 (gcc 4.6), on a dual quad-core nehalem, I get for psize-n_dead = 200000, running 100 iterations for better timer accuracy:

Struct of arrays (reported time are in milliseconds)

```
$ for t in 1 2 4 8; do export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$t; time ./foo; done
Took time 90.984000
Took time 45.992000
Took time 22.996000
Took time 11.998000
```

Array of structs:

```
$ for t in 1 2 4 8; do export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$t; time ./foo; done
Took time 58.989000
Took time 28.995000
Took time 14.997000
Took time 8.999000
```

However, I because the operation is so short (sub-ms) I didn't see any speedup without doing 100 iterations because of timer accuracy.  Also, you'd have to have a machine with good memory bandwidth to to get this sort of behaviour; you're only doing ~3 FMAs and another multiplication for every two pieces of data you read in.

Code for array-of-structs follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef struct particle_struct {
    double pos;
    double vel;
} particle;

typedef struct simulation_struct {
    particle *particles;
    double force;
} simulation;

void tick(struct timeval *t) {
    gettimeofday(t, NULL);
}

/* returns time in seconds from now to time described by t */
double tock(struct timeval *t) {
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    return (double)(now.tv_sec - t->tv_sec) + ((double)(now.tv_usec - t->tv_usec)/1000000.);
}


void update(simulation *s, unsigned psize, double dt) {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < psize; ++i)
    {
        s->particles[i].pos = s->particles[i].pos+ dt * s->particles[i].vel;
        s->particles[i].vel = (1 - dt*.1) * s->particles[i].vel + dt*s->force;
    }
}

void init(simulation *s, unsigned np) {
    s->force = 1.;
    s->particles = malloc(np*sizeof(particle));
    for (unsigned i=0; i<np; i++) {
        s->particles[i].pos = 1.;
        s->particles[i].vel = 1.;
}

int main(void)
{
    const unsigned np=200000;
    simulation s;
    struct timeval clock;

    init(&s, np);
    tick(&clock);
    for (int iter=0;iter< 100; iter++) 
        update(&s, np, 0.75);
    double elapsed=tock(&clock)*1000.;
    printf("Took time %lf\n", elapsed);

    free(s.particles);
}
```

Comment: I realized the main problem was that the cost of doing this set of operations was too small compared to the overall time cost, so I boosted the number of particles to increase the overall impact and demonstrate paralell efficeincy.